# Mutual information of Multivariate Gaussian Distribution

Tags: matrix

Consider N random variables $\mathbf{x}=[x_1,x_2,...,x_N]^T$ with joint density $p(\mathbf{x})$, and let $\mathbf{R}\in \mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ denote the covariance matrix. How to derive the mutual information for these multivariate Gaussian distributions?

Or do you know which literature provide the related derivation?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE! As currently posed, your question probably needs some editing to indicate what research you have already done, and where you are currently stuck. Also, if the question is asking for a derivation, it might be a better fit for Stats.SE after some editing for clarity.